# According to research, how well do speed reading skills transfer to other languages?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request, reading

According to Wikipedia, [speed reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_reading) is

> any of several techniques used to improve one's ability to read quickly. Speed reading methods include chunking and minimizing subvocalization.

There are very few articles on *how* to speed read in a foreign language, e.g.

- [Can We Speed Read in Foreign Languages?](http://ezinearticles.com/?Can-We-Speed-Read-in-Foreign-Languages?&id=2533635) by Kristjan-Olari Leping (June 2009).
- [How to Speed Read in a Foreign Language](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503151839/http://www.ehow.com/how_4422466_speed-read-foreign-language.html) by James Withers on eHow (now archived in the Internet Archive).

However, what I miss is any data, ideally from studies, about the **proficiency level needed for speed reading** (assuming that you are familiar with most of the vocabulary in the text you are reading) and **how speed reading in a foreign language impacts reading speed**.

Comment: I wonder if this would be more significantly affected by writing system or just by general proficiency in the language.

Comment: In my experience (I trained speed reading in my L1) it does not transfer very well. Even after many years, reading in my L2s is somehow slower.

Comment: @PeterMasiar Thanks for telling me about the redirect. I've looked for other articles (in English, German and French) but couldn't find any to replace Withers' article. Your experience is similar to mine; I think that speed reading requires at least level C1 in the CEFR.