# Online course or resources on speed reading in Chinese

Tags: reading, online-learning, chinese

In a comment to my previous question about the [transfer of speed reading skills to other languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2485/800), someone wondered whether this would be affected by the **writing system**. This is very plausible. In his [video on learning Russian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ltdv2kymcZo), Steve Kaufmann says that, in his own experience, (normal) reading in your "native writing system" is always easier (e.g. Czech versus Russian for a native speaker of English), so it is reasonable to assume that this also applies to speed reading (assuming the same amount of practice for Czech and Russian).

For a writing system that is very different, we can go to Chinese. I found out that Cheng & Tsui published [*A Course on Chinese Speed Reading*](https://www.cheng-tsui.com/browse/a-course-on-chinese-speed-reading) by Yang Li. However, I wonder if there any **online courses or online resources that teach speed reading in Chinese**.

Comment: In fact, the logographic writing systems has some intrinsic properties [eliminating the need](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2005/752) of many Rapid Reading techniques.

Comment: Here is an article giving advice: https://www.hackingchinese.com/learning-how-to-read-ten-lines-at-a-glance/. But it's not a course like you're looking for.

Comment: Additionally, it seems like recent scholarly literature suggests that Speed Reading in general may not be effective and is in fact largely a trade-off between speed and comprehension. http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1529100615623267. "If a thorough understanding of the text is not the reader’s goal, then speed reading or skimming the text will allow the reader to get through it faster with moderate comprehension. The way to maintain high comprehension and get through text faster is to practice reading and to become a more skilled language user (e.g., through increased vocabulary)."